# codeignitor routing not working correctly

Tags: codeigniter

I build a small CodeIgniter application and it works fine on my local but getting 404 error when I setup on server. I tried differnt ways but none is working. Any One can please help what I am doing wrong.

below is my routs.

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['default_controller'] = 'Upload';
$route['save'] = 'Upload/save';
$route['upload'] = 'Upload/do_upload';
```

and My controller is as below, My default controller only works but the rest doesn't work.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Upload extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library("session");
        $this->load->database();
        //load Model
        $this->load->model('UploadModel');

    }

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *        http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *    - or -
     *        http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *    - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $sort = $this->input->post('sorted');
        $order = $this->input->post('sort_order');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('sort', $sort);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('order', $order);
        $this->data['pictures'] = $this->UploadModel->getPicturesData('h_image_data',array('status' => 'approved'), $sort, $order);

        $data['success'] = '';
        $this->load->view('header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pictures_view', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
    
    public function save(){
        echo "Hello";
    }

   public function do_upload(){
echo "just remove the content to make the function clear";
}
}
```

Comment: check your base_url in config.php file

Comment: and .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think **letter case** is causing issue. If its a Linux hosting. Write controller name in lower case.

```
$route['save'] = 'upload/save';
$route['upload'] = 'upload/do_upload';
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your .htaccess file is located on root folder